# Call vbscript function to run on body onload in all browsers

Tags: javascript, function, vbscript

How can I get a vbscript function to run on body onload in all browsers?

This code (from w3schools) works in IE only:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
    function myFunction()
        alert("Hello World!")
    end function
</script>

</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
```

I want to replace the alert with the code that is already written in vbscript and is working as is. Can this be accomplished using javascript?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is: you can't.  To run cross-platform in the browser I recommend javascript.

Also, for code reference I would recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/), rather than w3schools.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to get this 'inherited' code over to javascript but my js knowledge isn't good enough at the moment.  The vbscript code is reading, writing, inserting etc into a database.  I don't want to mess it up.

Comment: VBscript can run on the web server-side quite happily, just not on the client end.

Comment: Sounds like you need to be running an ASP (Active Server Page) setup on the web server.  You're not going to successfully get database I/O with just javascript.

Comment: Yes.  I'm trying to set a new to a variable to a new value when the page is re-visited but this needs to include when the back button is pushed - and there I'm stumped.

Comment: How is the VBScript modifying a database? Is it using XMLHttpRequest? If not, it sounds like it would have to be runat="server", which means it shouldn't be making it to your client.

Answer (score 1):

Just about **everything** can be accomplished with Javascript. My *guess* is that only IE supports VBScript in `<script>` tags, but I'm not positive on that.

Anyway, to do it in Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        alert("Hello World!");
    }
</script>
```

The rest should be the same.

Comment: Yes I agree, but the code to be put in the function is already written in vbscript and it'll be a nightmare rewriting in javascript because someone else wrote it!

Comment: There is no other way around rewriting it.  VBScript is only supported in Microsoft Internet Explorer.